# Jquery размытие заднего плана

Tags: jquery

Доброго всем утра. Возникла передо мной такая задача: При перетаскивании какого - либо блока он должен становиться прозрачным, и размывать изображение позади него. Раньше никогда с таким не сталкивался, поэтому решил задачу так: При наведении блока на картинку присваиваю ему на бэкграунд эту самую картинку, и уже его размываю. А при движении просто меняю положение бэкграунда. Вот оно:
http://jsfiddle.net/BynX4/15/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.qwe').draggable({
    revert: 'invalid'      
  });
    $( ".qwe" ).mouseup(function() {
});


    $( "*" ).mousemove(function( event ) {
      if(parseInt($(".qwe").css("top"), 10) > 30 && parseInt($(".qwe").css("top"), 10) < 600 && parseInt($(".qwe").css("left"), 10) > -132 && parseInt($(".qwe").css("left"), 10) < 550)
    {
        $(".qwe").css("background","url(http://cs14107.vk.me/c540104/v540104856/8536/9V4EgXtH7RU.jpg) no-repeat");
        $(".qwe").css("background-position-x",-parseInt($(".qwe").css("left")));
        $(".qwe").css("background-position-y",-parseInt($(".qwe").css("top"))+100);
        $(".qwe").css("-webkit-filter","blur(5px)");
    }
        else
        {
            $(".qwe").css("background","white");
          $(".qwe").css("-webkit-filter","blur(0)");
        }
    });
});
```

(поводите квадратом по коту). Вопрос - можно ли это сделать по человечески, а не так, как я наворотил?

Comment: А что конкретно не по человечески тут , что собственно нужно ещё?
А да, оно не работает в других бразурех.